# Can't access vagrant urls from hosts.

Tags: windows, vagrant, virtualbox, puphpet

I am trying to setup my vagrant virtual box enviorment for development. Everything works fine. I have the shared folder setup and can access the information from my browser but only using the ip address. I can't use the `website.app` urls from windows even after i put it in my hosts file.

I used https://puphpet.com/ for the configuration file.

This is my hosts file:

`192.168.56.101 website.app`

Comment: whats happening when you hit `http://website.app` ? do you get HTTP error or you are redirected to the iP ?

Comment: I get an HTTP error
"This site can’t be reached"